# What is the problem with this quick sort in MIPS?

Tags: c, mips, mips32

This is the C code i am using to make the quick sort on the MIPS, on the Mars editor i am having issues when running these code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void QuickSort(int *array, int first, int last){
    int q;
    if (first<last){
        int value = array[last];
        int i = first-1;
        int tmp;
        int j = first;
        while(j<=last){
            if (array[j] <= value) {
              i++;
              tmp = array[i];
              array[i] = array[j];
              array[j] = tmp;
            }
          j++;
       }
       q = i;
       QuickSort(array,first,q-1);
       QuickSort(array,q+1,last);
    }
}
```

And this is my MIPS translation so far, i am getting an infinite loop

```
.data
numArray: 30, 15, 11, 40, 75, 80, 70, 60
first: 0
last: 7
    .text
main:
        la $a0, numArray
        lw $a1, first
        lw $a2, last
        jal quick_sort
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

quick_sort:
        subi $sp, $sp, 4        #reserving memory in the stack
        sw $ra, 4($sp)          #storing the return adress in the stack
        xor $t0, $t0, $t0       #int q
        bge $a1, $a2, label1    #if (first<last)
        sll $t1, $a2, 2         #int value = array[last];
        add $t1, $t1, $a0       #callculating array[last] in $t1
        lw $t1, 0($t1)          #array[last] = array direction + 4 * last
        or $t2, $t1, $zero      #$t2 will be value
        subi $t3, $a1, 1        #int i = first-1;
        xor $t4, $t4, $t4       #int tmp
        or $t5, $a1, $zero      #int j=first
        j label2                #while(j<=last)
    label3: sll $t6, $a2, 2     #calculating array[j] adress
        add $t6, $t6, $a0
        lw $t7, 0($t6)          #calculating array[j] value
        bgt $t7, $t1, label4    #if (array[j] <= value)
        addi $t3, $t3, 1        #i++
        sll $s0, $t3, 2         #calculating array[i] adress
        add $s0, $s0, $a0   
        lw $s1, 0($s0)          #calculating array[i] value
        or $t4, $s1, $zero      #tmp = array[i]
        sw $t7, 0($s0)          #array[i] = array[j];
        sw $t4, 0($t6)          #array[j] = tmp;
    label4: addi $t5, $t5, 1    #end if; j++
    label2: ble $t5, $a2, label3    #while condition
        or $t0, $t3, $zero      #q = i
        lw $a1, first           #first value on the second parameter
        subi $a2, $t0, 1        #q-1
        jal quick_sort          #QuickSort(array,first,q-1)
        addi $a1, $t0, 1        #q+1
        lw $a2, last            #last value on the third parameter
        jal quick_sort          #QuickSort(array,q+1,last);
    label1: lw $ra, 4($sp)      #Recovering the return address from the stack 
        addi $sp, $sp, 4        #releasing memory
        jr $ra                  #going to the return address
```

Maybe i need to store something more on the stack or something that i am missing, thanks for your help, anything that you see strange there please let me know to check it.

Comment: In `void QuickSort(int *array, int first, int last)` the first parameter is a pointer to `int`, but when calling `QuickSort(array, first, q-1)` are you sure it shouldn't be something like `QuickSort(&array[0], first, q-1)` ?

Comment: @luci88filter - no, they are the same thing.
There is no problem with the C code. It works fine.
The problem is somewhere in the assembly, but I am no sure where.
Jose - try stepping through the code one line at a time. There is a button for this in mars.

Comment: @Lev M. That is correct, the code seems to be working. A nice emulator for MIPS assembly would be nice, as I am very curious what the problem is.

Comment: @luci88filter the code if for the MARS simulator you can download for free from here: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/download.htm

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by Minn in a comment, I missed the two lines following:

```
sll $t1, $a2, 2         #int value = array[last];
```

So while this single line does not match the comment in it, the loading of the value seems correct.

**END EDIT**

I am not familiar with this specific assembly, but the problem seems to be what is known as ["register clobbering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) :

According to [documentation](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) `jal` only stores the return address, but does not store any of the registers.

```
    lw $a1, first           #first value on the second parameter
    subi $a2, $t0, 1        #q-1
    jal quick_sort          #QuickSort(array,first,q-1)
    addi $a1, $t0, 1        #q+1
    lw $a2, last            #last value on the third parameter
    jal quick_sort
```

You are using `$t0` as `q` local variable, but you never save it on the stack.

After the first call `jal quick_sort          #QuickSort(array,first,q-1)` the value of $t0 would be different, but you use it immediately in the line `addi $a1, $t0, 1        #q+1` as if it never changed, and then pass the result to the second call to `QuickSort`.

The C equivalent to this error would be to make `q` global and add `q = 0;` at the beginning of the function.

You must remember, that when working in assembly and using registers for local variables, you must save their state to the stack before calling any other function from your current function, otherwise you will lose state and your code will not work as expected!

To be honest, this is my first time seeing this particular assembly language, so there might be other errors I missed, but these are the most obvious ones so they were easy to spot.

Comment: The shift-left-logical is used because he wants to use word offsets (equivalent to times 4), so he is simply doing pointer arithmetic here. Although he doesn't use `.word` in the data segment which is a bit confusing. The three instructions are simply `*(array + last)` or `array[last]` as commented.

Comment: @Minn thanks, you were right, I missed the 2 lines after that one.